# Don't show links to duplicate questions if I cannot see them

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, related-questions, linked-questions, anonymous-visitors

I was browsing a Stack Exchange site where I am *not* a member - so I was browsing anonymously. I found an interesting question, read it, and then wanted to do further research. I checked out the right side panel and noticed some "Linked" questions.

I clicked on one and started to read it, only to realize that it was the question I had just read! I clicked again in the right panel and again the same question! Okay I was a little slow but eventually I realized that the linked question must be a duplicate of the current one.

So my feature request: If I don't have enough reputation to read the duplicate, don't show me the question link in the right hand panel. I should note that I did see the same link under both the "Linked" questions as well as "Related" questions.

The current behavior may be confusing for users who don't realize what is happening.

For the troubleshooters:

Question I was reading: [Can Ubuntu run on a Microsoft Surface with Windows RT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206141/can-ubuntu-run-on-a-microsoft-surface-with-windows-rt)

The "duplicate": [Is there an ARM based ubuntu OS I can install on the Microsoft Surface RT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330503/is-there-an-arm-based-ubuntu-os-i-can-install-on-the-microsoft-surface-rt?lq=1)

Comment: did the question look [like this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/c-code-design-issue "an example of a merged question")?

Comment: @gnat - not quite sure what you are looking for, but I added the questions in my edit above.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Anonymous users are automatically redirected to the marked duplicate.

Comment: @TimStone thanks, learn something new all the time.  I guess I should browse as an anonymous user more often

Comment: @TimStone I would say that happens only for merged questions. I just tested - anonymously opening a "regular" (not a merged) dupe doesn't play tricks like that

Comment: @gnat There's a prerequisite that the question closed as a duplicate doesn't have any answers. You can reproduce using the example in the question.

Comment: @TimStone you're right, I just tested