# Clicking on vote count in the Linked Questions list does not give a “noredirect” link

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions, linked-questions, redirection

#### The problem

According to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281008), linked questions in the sidebar should have `noredirect=1` passed. This was done due to an annoying redirect (explained better in the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280895) than I ever could):

> For anonymous, not-logged-in users, duplicate questions automatically redirect to the dupe target.
>
> In this case, this results in a poor user experience for anonymous users, since they click on the linked question in the sidebar, only to be taken back to where they were. My reaction when I experienced this while not logged in was pretty much "Huh, what's going on here ?".

This works all fine and dandy if you click on the *question title*, which is what I suspect the majority of users will try. However, as a lazy user of other SE sites, I know that I don’t have to move my mouse all the way over the title. Clicking on the vote count should work just fine. Except it doesn’t here - since the apparently separate link in the *vote count box* does not pass `noredirect=1` as the question title does.

<sub>Yes this is a very small problem but I have run into it one too many times now</sub>

#### Example

[image: vote count box circled in red, and question title circled in green]

[Question in screenshot above.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216080) Clicking on [‘Add the ability to create any tag synonym to the “trusted user” privileges’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives me a `noredirect=1` link. Clicking on the [“70” of the vote count box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79151?lq=1) doesn’t, and thus leads me (when logged out/anonymous) straight back to the original question. This seems like obviously unintended behavior, since it’s what the bugfix was supposed to stop.

#### Non-dupes of this question

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339588) is not a duplicate as it is about the *page of linked questions* ([example given in that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/58032?lq=1)) that you get by clicking on “see more linked questions”, when there are too many linked questions to display on the sidebar. I am asking about links *from the sidebar*, directly, not from this other page.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217756) is not a duplicate as it is asking to not show the links at all. It also appears to be older than the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [question I linked at the start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280895), which was “fixed” by passing `noredirect=1` for question-title links. I am asking about a specific oversight of that newer question’s fix.

<sub>If there's a duplicate of this question, I'm very sorry, you can close this as an unanswered dupe and give another example of the bug :)</sub>